# Estimate the basic reproductive number(R0) of Covid-19 using the next-generation matrix(NGM)

Tags: r

I want to estimate the basic reproductive number(R0) of Covid-19 using the next-generation matrix method. I have a complemental model as follows:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(deSolve)
library(rootSolve)
pars<- c( R0=8,inter.eff=0.75,
      inter.start=1,e.dur=3,i.dur=10,cfr=0.0003)
tout  <- seq(1, 2, by = 1)
  
  derivs <- function(t, state, pars){
    with(as.list(c(state, pars)),{
      num <- S + E + I + R# Population size
      
      # Effective contact rate and FOI from a rearrangement of Beta * c * D
      ce <- R0 / i.dur
      lambda <- ce * I/num
      if (!is.null(inter.eff) && t >= inter.start) {
        lambda <- lambda * (1 - inter.eff)
      }
      dS <- -lambda*S
      dE <- lambda*S - (1/e.dur)*E
      dI <- (1/e.dur)*E - (1 - cfr)*(1/i.dur)*I - cfr*(1/i.dur)*I
      dR <- (1 - cfr)*(1/i.dur)*I
      
      # Compartments and flows are part of the derivative vector
      # Other calculations to be output are outside the vector, but within the containing list
      list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR))
    })
    }
```

And consequently, an ordinary differential system as follows:

```
v<-as.data.frame( ode(y = c(S=64000000, 
                                 E=1000, I=5, R=3),
                           times = tout, func = derivs,
                           parms = pars,method = "euler"))
```

In the next step, I want to estimate the Jacobin matrix for each row of the `v`.The last code I wrote for this purpose was as follows, but unfortunately, I did not get the result. So that a matrix is estimated as a whole and not for each row of the `v`.Please help me if possible.

```
v<- v[,-c(1)]#Delete time column
  for (i in 1:nrow(v) ){
    r<-jacobian.full(y= c(S=v[i,1], E=v[i,2], I=v[i,3], 
                          R=v[i,4]), 
                     func=derivs, 
                     parms =pars, 
                     pert = 1e-8)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
`product = function(x, output){
S=x[1]
E=x[2]
I= x[3]
R=x[4]
w<-jacobian.full(y= c(S, E, I, 
                R), 
           func=derivs, 
           parms =pars, 
           pert = 1e-8)
# return product
return(as.data.frame( w))
}

single <- apply(v,1,product  )`
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more rather than just posting code?